# Is there any number that is not the sum of the proper factors of another integer.

Tags: number-theory

I was thinking about perfect numbers, and started to make a tree, where the number connected to a number above is the sum of the second numbers proper factors.  This branches out a lot, forming a forest of trees, with each perfect or set of amicable nunbers number establishing a new tree.  My question was this:  does each branch extend indefinitely?  A way to think about this is whether or not there is any number which is not the sum of the proper  factors of another integer, as long as the integer is not itself and the numbers don't get caught in an amicable circle.

Comment: Just write down small numbers.  If you are only using positive divisors, as I assume you are, you will find small counterexamples.

Comment: Are there infinitely many counterexamples?

Comment: Well, I'd certainly think so.  Not immediately clear (to me) how to prove that.  [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C3%2C1%2C6%2C1%2C7%2C4%2C8&language=english&go=Search) is the OEIS sequence of the sum of the proper divisors of the integers.  Perhaps one of the links attached to that proves that the list misses a lot of integers.

Comment: According to [this paper](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/firstfunctionbcmit.pdf) Erdos proved that there is a positive proportion of even numbers that are not the sum of proper divisors of an integer).  It is imagined that all odd numbers (other than $5$) are the sum of proper divisors, the paper I linked to claims this follows from a strengthen form of Goldbach (again a result of Erdos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5 is not the sum of the proper factors of any integer.

Comment: Why?  Is there some way to prove that?

Comment: There are only two ways to write 5 as a sum of distinct positive integers, $5=1+4$ and $5=2+3$. There is no integer that has 1 and 4 as its only proper factors, since if 4 is a proper factor, so is 2. There is no positive integer that has 2 and 3 as its only proper factors, since if 2 is a proper factor, so is 1.

Comment: Any further questions about this?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Yes.  Thanks for the proof of the inexistence of a number for 5.  Are there infinitely many of these?

Comment: According to a comment by @lulu, Erdos proved there's a positive density (a fortiori, infinitely many) of them.